# How to use \verb in the environment tabular?

Tags: tables

I proposed to put a `\verb|\sffamily|` into a `multicolumn` command as the 3rd parameter, but LaTeX referred 3 errors. Here is my code.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}\hline
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\verb|\sffamily|} 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

And here is my errors
[image: Screenshot 2019-01-31_19-57-04.png]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The earlier answers cover the standard approaches to a case like this:  use `\texttt` (either directly or through a new command), or somehow save the verbatim content in a normal context and then load it later.

Here is an alternate approach that uses `fvextra`.  This requires v1.4, the newest version.  `fvextra` now provides a `\Verb` command (note capitalization) that works inside other commands under most circumstances, with a few limitations such as no `#` or `%`.  Details about limitations are in the documentation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{fvextra}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}\hline
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\Verb|\sffamily|} 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

`fvextra` now also provides a command `\EscVerb` for the cases when `\Verb` won't work inside another command.  `\EscVerb` is similar to `\Verb` and the normal `\verb`, except that the backslash serves as an escape character (`\\` becomes `\`, `\#` becomes `#`, etc.), and the argument must be delimited with a pair of curly braces.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{fvextra}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}\hline
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\EscVerb{\\sffamily}} 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way.  Save the verbatim stuff in a `verbbox` before the `tabular`, and then invoke it from within the `tabular`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,verbatimbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{myverbbox}{\sfverb}\sffamily\end{myverbbox}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\sfverb}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Above, I use a named `verbbox`.  If there is only one needed at a time, you can just use the default-named `verbbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,verbatimbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbbox}\sffamily\end{verbbox}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\theverbbox}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yeah it's a nice solution, using box to fix this problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `\verb` in the argument to another command, in this case `\multicolumn`.

For the specific problem, `\verb` is not necessary; I suggest to do

```
\newcommand{\cs}[1]{\texttt{\symbol{`\\}#1}}
```

and now

```
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cs{sffamily}}
```

will work.

Comment: In other cases , we can use `\cprotect` to make `\verb` works. But this method seems not to work...

Comment: @Syvshc The package says “Include `\verb` anywhere!”, but it should say *almost anywhere*; the problem here is that `\multicol` *must* come first in a cell: either at the immediate beginning of a row or just after `&` (spaces are ignored). Using `\cprotect\multicolumn` defeats this.

Comment: I don't really understand what ''defeat'' here...

Comment: @Syvshc If `\multicolumn` is after `\cprotect`, it can't work.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `verbdef` to define a macro with the verbatim content outside the tabular and then use the macro inside it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{verbdef}
\begin{document}
\verbdef\myverbtext|\sffamily|
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}\hline
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\myverbtext}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The `newverbs` package also provides a `\collectverb{<code>}<char><verbatim><char>` macro which collects the verbatim for you and feeds it to a macro. However, `\collectverb{\multicolumn{2}{c|}}|\sffamily|` does not work here as `\collectverb` is not allowed between tabular rows (`! Misplaced \omit.`).